# Random variable and independence on unit interval

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have a simple probability question that has been confusing me.

Lets say I generate a random variable $X$ drawn from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Now, lets define two real (nonrandom) numbers $p,q\in[0,1]$.
Define event $A$ to be the event that $X\leq p$.
Define event $B$ to be the event that $X \geq (1-q)$.

My question is, for what values of p and q are A and B independent?

My idea is that these two events will be dependent when there is a nonempty intersection between $X\leq p$ and $X \geq (1-q)$ and independent if this intersection is empty. So my answer is that $A$ and $B$ are independent when $p-(1-q)\leq 0$. I was hoping someone could help me know if I am correct and if this equality in my inequality answer relating $p$ and $q$ should be strictly less than? My confusion with this arises because of this boundary when $p=1-q$.

Comment: If the intersection between $X \leq p$ and $X \geq 1-q$ is empty, then knowing that $X \leq p$ means that $X \geq 1-q$ is not the case. Mutually exclusive events are always dependent.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(B)$.  In this case, $\mathbb P(A) = p$, $\mathbb P(B) = q$, $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = p - (1-q) = p+q-1$ if $p \ge 1-q$, $0$ otherwise.  So for independence you need $p q = p+q-1$ or $p q = 0$.  But $pq - (p+q-1) = (p-1)(q-1)$.  Thus the condition is that $p=0$ or $p=1$ or $q=0$ or $q=1$.

Comment: You said that independence only occurs here if $p\geq 1-q$, but shouldn't this be when $p\leq 1-q$?

Comment: No.  When $p \le 1-q$ the intervals don't overlap and $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = 0$.  In that case, in order for the events to be independent we need either $\mathbb P(A)=0$ or $\mathbb P(B)=0$.